# Maximum Windows username length - Maximum allowable file path length for Windows Store App

Tags: .net, windows, windows-runtime

I'm running into PathTooLong exceptions in my Windows 8 app.

Since the path is of the form: `C:\Users\{user}\AppData\Local\Packages\{appid}\LocalState\` ...  I'm wondering how many characters I have left.   What is the maximum size for {user} on a Windows 8 or Windows 10 machine?

Answer (score 1):

> [PathTooLongException]: The specified path, file name, or both are too long. The fully qualified file name must be less than 260 characters, and the directory name must be less than 248 characters.

Here is link to MSDN with details on naming files and folders: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365247(VS.85).aspx

> Username is a string with a maximum length of 256 characters.

And here is link to MSDN with details on user name restrictions: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/dn965864(v=vs.85).aspx

Answer (score 0):

Windows 8.1 seems to limit you to 20 characters when adding a non-Microsoft account